# WPF, C#, TaskbarItemInfo: Hide Thumbnail-Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, thumbnails, taskbar

is it possible to prevent windows (7) from popping up the thumbnail window?
I made a little wpf-app, start it from the taskbar, the app window opens right above the taskbar and is immediatly covered by the thumbnail window.
Thanks for help,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible in Vista, but in Windows 7 you can't hide it.  Well, you can always switch to Windows Basic theme but I'm sure that's not a practical option.

It only shows when the mouse is over the taskbar button so your users will have to put the mouse on your app's window instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, David. The problem is, the app window isn't much bigger than the thumbnail and if the user isn't fast enough to move the mouse away from the taskbar, he can't acces the app window until the thumbnail dissapeasrs... I guess they won't accept this...

Comment: I can see that this is troublesome.